# React Highchart on select event not getting any values in target object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

i am  trying to access the properties of a chart point in a Highcharts chart that is being used in a React application, but when i click on the point, the event.target object that is passed to the event handler function is showing all keys as null.

my graph has some filters to sort data by week, last 30 days, custom, and today.

when i click on any point before filtering event.target function shows object fulfilled with every key but when i filtered and my gaprh gets updated with new value which works fine but event.target start showing all keys as null

```
export const getChartConfig = (
  showingStats,
  data,
  labels,
  graphFilter,
  filter,
  dates,
  pointerClickSetter,
) => {
  let line1Data = [];
  let line2Data = [];
  let line3Data = [];
  let line4Data = [];

  let line5Data = [];
  let line6Data = [];
  let yAxisLabels = ['', ''];
  const totalNeeded = labels.length;
  const totalFilled = data.length;
  if (totalNeeded === totalFilled) {
    Array(totalNeeded)
      .fill(0)
      .map((item, index) => {
        line1Data.push([labels[index], data[index].panelPower]);
        line2Data.push([labels[index], data[index].panelVoltage]);
        line3Data.push([labels[index], data[index].batteryVoltage]);
        line4Data.push([labels[index], data[index].batteryPower]);
        line5Data.push([labels[index], data[index].generatedEnergy]);
        line6Data.push([labels[index], data[index].consumedEnergy]);
      });
  } else {
    if (filter === 'hourly') {
      labels.map((item) => {
        const indexOf = [...data].findIndex((eachItem) => {
          if (dayjs().date() == dayjs(eachItem.date).utc().format('DD')) {
            return dayjs(eachItem.date).utc().format('HH') == item;
          }
        });
        if (indexOf !== -1) {
          const format = dayjs(data[indexOf].date).utc().format('HH');
          if (format == item) {
            line1Data.push([item, data[indexOf].panelPower]);
            line2Data.push([item, data[indexOf].panelVoltage]);
            line3Data.push([item, data[indexOf].batteryVoltage]);
            line4Data.push([item, data[indexOf].batteryPower]);
            line5Data.push([item, data[indexOf].generatedEnergy]);
            line6Data.push([item, data[indexOf].consumedEnergy]);
          } else {
            line1Data.push([item, 0]);
            line2Data.push([item, 0]);
            line3Data.push([item, 0]);
            line4Data.push([item, 0]);
            line5Data.push([item, 0]);
            line6Data.push([item, 0]);
          }
        } else {
          line1Data.push([item, 0]);
          line2Data.push([item, 0]);
          line3Data.push([item, 0]);
          line4Data.push([item, 0]);
          line5Data.push([item, 0]);
          line6Data.push([item, 0]);
        }
      });
    } else if (filter === 'daily') {
      const lastNDays = graphFilter === 'Last 7 Days' ? getLastNDays(7) : labels;
      lastNDays.map((item, index) => {
        const indexOf = [...data].findIndex((eachItem) => {
          return dayjs(eachItem.date).utc().format('DD-MMM-YYYY') === item;
        });
        if (indexOf !== -1) {
          line1Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].panelPower]);
          line2Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].panelVoltage]);
          line3Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].batteryVoltage]);
          line4Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].batteryPower]);
          line5Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].generatedEnergy]);
          line6Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].consumedEnergy]);
        } else {
          line1Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line2Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line3Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line4Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line5Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line6Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
        }
      });
    } else if (filter === 'weekly') {
      const lastNWeeks = getNWeeks(5);
      const lastNDays = getLastNDays(30);
      let tempDates = [...data].map((eachItem) => dayjs(eachItem.date).utc().format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
      let includedArr = tempDates.map((tempDate) => {
        let tempDateObj = dayjs(tempDate);
        for (let i = 0; i <= lastNWeeks.length - 1; i++) {
          if (dayjs(tempDateObj > lastNWeeks[i]) && tempDateObj < dayjs(lastNWeeks[i + 1])) {
            return lastNWeeks[i];
          }
        }
      });

      lastNWeeks.map((item, index) => {
        const indexOf = includedArr.indexOf(item);
        if (indexOf !== -1) {
          line1Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].panelPower]);
          line2Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].panelVoltage]);
          line3Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].batteryVoltage]);
          line4Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].batteryPower]);
          line5Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].generatedEnergy]);
          line6Data.push([labels[index], data[indexOf].consumedEnergy]);
        } else {
          line1Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line2Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line3Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line4Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line5Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
          line6Data.push([labels[index], 0]);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  const allSeries = [];
  if (showingStats[0].showing) {
    allSeries.push(getSeriesConfig('#5ad8a6', line1Data, 'Solid', 0, false));
  }
  if (showingStats[1].showing) {
    allSeries.push(getSeriesConfig('#5ad8a6', line2Data, 'ShortDot', 1, true));
  }
  if (showingStats[2].showing) {
    allSeries.push(getSeriesConfig('#e8684a', line3Data, 'ShortDot', 0, false));
  }
  if (showingStats[3].showing) {
    allSeries.push(getSeriesConfig('#e8684a', line4Data, 'Solid', 1, true));
  }
  if (showingStats[4].showing) {
    allSeries.push(getSeriesConfig('#0000FF', line5Data, 'Solid', 0, false));
  }
  if (showingStats[5].showing) {
    allSeries.push(getSeriesConfig('#0000FF', line6Data, 'ShortDot', 1, true));
  }

  showingStats.forEach((stat) => {
    if (stat.value.includes('voltage') && stat.showing) {
      yAxisLabels[1] = 'Voltage (Volts)';
    }

    if (stat.value.includes('current') && stat.showing) {
      yAxisLabels[0] = 'Current (Amperes)';
    }
  });

  const options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      zoomType: 'x',
    },
    reflow: true,
    credits: false,
    exporting: {
      enabled: false,
    },

    title: {
      text: '',
    },
    // Current (Amperes)
    //
    yAxis: [
      {
        // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
          text: yAxisLabels[0],
        },
        labels: {
          format: '{value}',
        },
      },
      {
        // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
          format: '{value}',
        },
        title: {
          text: yAxisLabels[1],
        },
        opposite: true,
      },
    ],

    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      tickInterval: 1,
      categories: [...labels],
      accessibility: {
        rangeDescription: '',
      },
      crosshair: {
        width: 1,
        color: '#2296f3',
      },
    },

    plotOptions: {
      spline: {
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true, //shows dots when hover on the line
          },
        },
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        point: {
          events: {
            select: pointerClickSetter, //<---- here is the problem --- pointerClickSetter is a setter funtion of useState --- 
          },
        },
        // data: allSeries,
        label: {
          connectorAllowed: true,
        },
        pointStart: 1,
      },
    },

    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      borderColor: '#ffffff',
      crosshairs: [true, false],
      formatter: function () {
        const value1 = line1Data[labels.indexOf(this.x)][1].toFixed(2) || 0;
        const value2 = line2Data[labels.indexOf(this.x)][1].toFixed(2) || 0;
        const value3 = line3Data[labels.indexOf(this.x)][1].toFixed(2) || 0;
        const value4 = line4Data[labels.indexOf(this.x)][1].toFixed(2) || 0;
        const value5 = line5Data[labels.indexOf(this.x)][1].toFixed(2) || 0;
        const value6 = line6Data[labels.indexOf(this.x)][1].toFixed(2) || 0;
        return (
          'Panel Voltage: <b>' +
          value2 +
          'V</b>' +
          '<br><br>Panel Current: <b>' +
          value1 +
          'A</b>' +
          '<br><br>Battery Voltage: <b>' +
          value4 +
          'V</b>' +
          '<br><br>Battery Current: <b>' +
          value3 +
          'A</b>' +
          '</b>' +
          '<br><br>Solar Generation: <b>' +
          value5 +
          'Wh</b>' +
          '</b>' +
          '<br><br>Power Consumption: <b>' +
          value6 +
          'Wh</b>'
        );
      },
    },
    series: [...allSeries],
  };

  return options;
};


 <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={getChartConfig(
          showingStats,
          data,
          labels,
          graphFilter,
          graphSubFilter,
          currentDates,
          chartPointerSetter,
        )}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `getChartConfig` function is called again on state change which triggers unnecessary chart updating through the `HighchartsReact` component.

You should keep your chart options in a state, memorize them or if your chart is static, disable the `allowChartUpdate` option.

```
  <HighchartsReact
    ...
    allowChartUpdate={false}
  />
```

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update